# QGIS dxf2shp text angle problem

Tags: qgis, dxf

I am trying to convert from dxf to shp. Any text layer when converted has attributes including text, height, and angle. The angle is in radians, and I can see that it is in degrees in the dxf file. QGIS displays the text as if the angle was in degrees. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In Qgis Edit the rotation Field to the Formula, degrees( "angle") where angle is the field that has the Text angle rotation.